# I have issue with showing my chart after getting all necessary data

Tags: symfony, twig, morris.js

my script is

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.oesmith.co.uk/morris-0.4.1.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<script>
Morris.Line({
  element: 'line-example',
  data: [
  {% for toto in totos %}
{y:{{toto.dateEffet }} ,a:{{toto.montantTotal }}}
{% endfor %}
  ],
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a'],
});
</script>
```

my repository is

```
 public function TotalContrat()
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('co');

        $qb->select('COUNT(co.id)AS montantTotal')
            ->addSelect('co.dateEffet AS dateEffet ')
            ->groupBy('co.dateEffet')
        ->orderBy('co.dateEffet', 'ASC');

        return $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
    }
```

and my fonction in my controller is

```
public function AccueilAction() {
    $toto =$em->getRepository('Bundle:Contrat')->TotalContrat();
    return $this->render('Bundle:Pages:Accueil.html.twig',array(
        'totalContrat'=>$toto
    )); }
```

and after refresh the page i cant see my graph but when i cheak the response in my cpnsole i see this

```
<script>
Morris.Line({
  element: 'line',
  data: [
  {y:2017-08-04 00:00:00.000 ,a:16}
{y:2017-08-09 00:00:00.000 ,a:3}
{y:2017-08-10 00:00:00.000 ,a:11}
{y:2017-08-15 00:00:00.000 ,a:1}
{y:2017-08-16 00:00:00.000 ,a:1}
{y:2017-09-15 00:00:00.000 ,a:2}
  ],
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a'],
});
</script>
```

so i think it get data and put it on x and y keys but it show nothin in my twig

Comment: What is your desired behaviour and how it differs from current behaviour? Add it to the question(not in comments).

Comment: some errors in the browser's console? ([from the doc](https://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/lines.html) seem that the attribute `labels` is required the date format seem os, but i don't know this library)

Comment: i wanna show my graph in my twig caus it show nothing in the <div> i think i explained all

Comment: yes Matteo i did it and stil nothing and no errors

Comment: the elements of the data array keys are missing of a comma between every element

Comment: didnt u_nderstund Matteo can u please explaine more for me

Comment: darkbee if u can see my code its exactly what i did

Comment: Hence the comma at the end, that is what Matteo was on about as well

Comment: `{% for toto in totos %}{y:{{toto.dateEffet }} ,a:{{toto.montantTotal }}},{% endfor %}`

Comment: darkbee i did but nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

i solve the problem by adding '' to ykey so

```
{% for toto in totos %}
{y:'{{toto.dateEffet }}' ,a:{{toto.montantTotal }}},
{% endfor %}
```